# Saving Blocks of cropped image Resulted from blockproc in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I've been trying to crop and save the blocks (subimages) from the original image using blockproc and imcrop functions, but I couldn't. I'm only able to see the figures of the blocks. Is there any way to save these blocks to the specified folder? Thanks.

```
clear all
close all
clc
a = imread('3.jpg');
folderPath='C:\Program Files\Folder';
blockSize = [70,70];
d = blockproc(a,blockSize,@(bs) imcrop(bs.data));
%blockproc(a, blockSize, @(bs)imcrop(bs.data),'BorderSize', [1 1 ]);

%i=1;
fileName = [folderPath num2str(i) '.jpg'];
imwrite(d, fileName, 'jpg');
```

Comment: What are the dimensions of `d`?

Comment: 3 dimensions of RGB image

Answer (score 0):

My assumption from the information you have in the question, "you want to bring up every 70x70 block of your image and then crop out a smaller part in this 70x70 block using IMCROP and save that smaller region to a file". (If that is not your intention, please do update the question).

You could do this by using this function (air code, hope you get the idea)

In cropAndSaveBlock.m:

```
function cropAndSaveBlock(bs)
   subBlockRegion = imcrop(bs.data);
   % Use location of the block to come up with a unique name
   fileName = [strrep(num2str(bs.location),' ','_') '.jpg'];
   imwrite(sbBlockRegion, fileName);
end
```

And then call it using:

```
blockproc(a,blockSize,@cropAndSaveBlock);
```